# Exception while setting up JOGL with IntelliJ

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, jogl

this is my first question on stackoverflow so please forgive me if I am not specific enough but I'll give my best.
So here's my problem:
For 3 hours I've been trying to setup jogl with IntelliJ. Followed the instructions on the jogl installation homepage for my OS and IntelliJ recognizes all OpenGL classes without problems. Source code is being read without errors but here's the thing: When I try to start my program I get this error:

```java
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/jogamp_0000/file_cache/jln3160951728563156885/jln8316311171870168112/natives/linux-amd64/libnativewindow_awt.so: /usr/lib/jvm/java-13-oracle/lib/libjawt.so: version `SUNWprivate_1.1' not found (required by /tmp/jogamp_0000/file_cache/jln3160951728563156885/jln8316311171870168112/natives/linux-amd64/libnativewindow_awt.so)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(ClassLoader.java:2440)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2497)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:2694)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2627)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:744)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1873)
    at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.loadLibraryInternal(JNILibLoaderBase.java:603)
    at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.access$000(JNILibLoaderBase.java:63)
    at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase$DefaultAction.loadLibrary(JNILibLoaderBase.java:106)
    at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.loadLibrary(JNILibLoaderBase.java:487)
    at jogamp.nativewindow.NWJNILibLoader.access$000(NWJNILibLoader.java:39)
    at jogamp.nativewindow.NWJNILibLoader$1.run(NWJNILibLoader.java:49)
    at jogamp.nativewindow.NWJNILibLoader$1.run(NWJNILibLoader.java:41)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312)
    at jogamp.nativewindow.NWJNILibLoader.loadNativeWindow(NWJNILibLoader.java:41)
    at jogamp.nativewindow.jawt.JAWTUtil.<clinit>(JAWTUtil.java:336)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:416)
    at com.jogamp.nativewindow.NativeWindowFactory$3.run(NativeWindowFactory.java:344)
    at com.jogamp.nativewindow.NativeWindowFactory$3.run(NativeWindowFactory.java:340)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312)
    at com.jogamp.nativewindow.NativeWindowFactory.initSingleton(NativeWindowFactory.java:340)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.initProfilesForDefaultDevices(GLProfile.java:1721)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.access$000(GLProfile.java:80)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile$1.run(GLProfile.java:230)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.initSingleton(GLProfile.java:216)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.getProfileMap(GLProfile.java:2297)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.get(GLProfile.java:988)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.getDefault(GLProfile.java:722)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.getDefault(GLProfile.java:733)
    at PongGame.run(Pong3DTex.java:217)
    at Pong3DTex$1.run(Pong3DTex.java:1028)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)'"
```

And I have literally no clue about what is happening, why this is happening and what 'SUNWprivate_1.1' is supposed to be. The line the exception is referring to says: `GLProfile glp = GLProfile.getDefault();` which is like literally the first line that's executed in my code.

This is all happening on my Laptop running the latest version of elementaryOS and I am pretty new to Linux so I am totally overwhelmed atm. On Windows everything worked fine when I told IntelliJ the path to the jar folder of jogl and that was it.

So I really hope you guys can help me because I am at the end of my wisdom. Thanks for every answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright. So after 6 hours of research, reinstalling java/jogl over and over again I found the problem: I used oracle jdk13, which doesn't seem to be compatible with jogl on linux so i uninstalled jdk13 and downloaded open jdk 11 instead. Still doesn't wort but i get a different exception message. Threw away open jdk 11 and installed open jdk 8 instead et voila -> IT FINALLY WORKS. 8 Hours I had to use for study wasted on such a crap. Why can't stuff just work on linux? why does there always have to be some hidden bs that's stopping you from doing the things you need to do? – CaptainIceBl0ck 24 mins ago

Comment: Sorry to be a bit harsh. At first, JOGL-specific questions should be asked on the official JogAmp forum as only a few contributors are frequently on SO. Secondly, nowhere you mention which version of JOGL you use, JOGL 2.3.2 (the current latest version) doesn't fully support Java >=9 whereas JOGL 2.4.0 does, please use the latest nightly build.

Comment: By the way, I have used JOGL under GNU Linux since 2006 (I'm currently under Mageia Linux 7) and it works like a charm. As I'm a real supporter of free software, I don't install Oracle Java, I use only OpenJDK. If you need a very recent version of Java not bundled with your distribution, have a look at adoptopenjdk.net. Please spend some time in talking about your very first error message here: http://forum.jogamp.org/jogl-f782158.html

Comment: I mention your very first problem here: http://forum.jogamp.org/Oracle-Java-13-Linux-version-SUNWprivate-1-1-not-found-td4040172.html

Comment: Thanks for your help so far and I am sorry for being so grumpy yesterday. I was just really frustrated because I had to waste so much time on something rather simple and couldn't study properly. The thing why I used oracle java 13 is because it was specifically requested by our Project Manager which is why I was so reclusive to installing different versions..

Comment: That's really nice to hear. Thank you very much for being so helpful.

Comment: You're welcome. Xerxes tested JOGL 2.4.0 with Java 13 and he confirmed that it works fine :) http://forum.jogamp.org/Oracle-Java-13-Linux-version-SUNWprivate-1-1-not-found-tp4040172p4040175.html Maybe you can go on with OpenJDK 8 + JOGL 2.3.2 until Sven releases JOGL 2.4.0.